# RestTemplate GET request with request params

Tags: parameters, get, request, rest-client, resttemplate

I have to call a REST webservice and I am planning to use RestTemplate. I looked at examples on how to make a GET request and they are as shown below.

```
 String result = restTemplate.getForObject("http://example.com/hotels/{hotel}/bookings/{booking}", String.class,"42","21");
```

In my case the RESTful url is something like below. How do I use RestTemplate in this case?

```
http://example.com/hotels?state=NY&country=USA
```

So my question would be how do I send request parameters for GET requests?

Answer (score 35):

the placeholders work the same for either type of url, just do

```
 String result = restTemplate.getForObject("http://example.com/hotels?state={state}&country={country}", String.class,"NY","USA");
```

or better yet, use a hashmap for real name matching-

Answer (score 1):

While making a request to a RESTful server, it requires in many a cases to send query parameters, request body (in case of `POST` and `PUT` request methods), as well as headers in the request to the server.

In such cases, the URI string can be built using [UriComponentsBuilder.build()](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/util/UriComponentsBuilder.html#build--), encoded using [UriComponents.encode()](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/util/UriComponents.html#encode--) if needed to, and sent using [RestTemplate.exchange()](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/client/RestTemplate.html#exchange-java.net.URI-org.springframework.http.HttpMethod-org.springframework.http.HttpEntity-java.lang.Class-) like this:

```java
public ResponseEntity<String> requestRestServerWithGetMethod()
{
    HttpEntity<?> entity = new HttpEntity<>(requestHeaders); // requestHeaders is of HttpHeaders type
    UriComponentsBuilder builder = UriComponentsBuilder.fromUriString(rawValidUrl) // rawValidURl = http://example.com/hotels
            .queryParams(
                    (LinkedMultiValueMap<String, String>) allRequestParams); // The allRequestParams must have been built for all the query params
    UriComponents uriComponents = builder.build().encode(); // encode() is to ensure that characters like {, }, are preserved and not encoded. Skip if not needed.
    ResponseEntity<Object> responseEntity = restTemplate.exchange(uriComponents.toUri(), HttpMethod.GET,
            entity, String.class);
    return responseEntity;
}

public ResponseEntity<String> requestRestServerWithPostMethod()
{
    HttpEntity<?> entity = new HttpEntity<>(requestBody, requestHeaders); // requestBody is of string type and requestHeaders is of type HttpHeaders
    UriComponentsBuilder builder = UriComponentsBuilder.fromUriString(rawValidUrl) // rawValidURl = http://example.com/hotels
            .queryParams(
                    (LinkedMultiValueMap<String, String>) allRequestParams); // The allRequestParams must have been built for all the query params
    UriComponents uriComponents = builder.build().encode(); // encode() is to ensure that characters like {, }, are preserved and not encoded. Skip if not needed.
    ResponseEntity<Object> responseEntity = restTemplate.exchange(uriComponents.toUri(), HttpMethod.POST,
            entity, String.class);
    return responseEntity;
}
```